# github Fork question

Tags: github

If I have forked a project and started to work on it, Does that fork belong to me or does it belong to the owner of the original source ?

Also if the code pretty much has gone from being procedural to OO aswell as going from SQLLite to a MySQLi can I just create my own project and use my code ?

Answer (score 1):

It belongs to you, you can do whatever you want.